# SQL Server 2012 CLR Assembly - Parameter Counts Don't Match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

**A little history**: We have successfully (2 years ago) built .NET CLR code for SQL Server, compiled to an assembly, and loaded into a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise database. We then created the TSQL objects to call the CLR code. This has been working without issue since first installation and we have modified it over the years without issue.

**Today**: We have a need to modify the CLR code. Doing this in Visual Studio causes no issues with compiling to an assembly. The signatures for functions referenced by TSQL have not changed at all (all parameters, parameter types, etc. have not changed). The modifications were to re-factor some of the underlying code in the functions and create a couple new functions (all of which are private static and do not get referenced in TSQL). We are now in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (the upgrade went off without an issue in mid 2015 and the DB is in 2012 compatibility mode now).

I can successfully drop and re-create the assembly in SQL Server. When re-creating the TSQL objects that rely on the assembly some bind to the CLR function signatures without issue but the one that was re-factored will not re-create. This error message is

```
Msg 6550, Level 16, State 2, Procedure udfGetCellValueCLR, Line 2
CREATE FUNCTION failed because parameter counts do not match.
```

The parameters did not change in any way. When I look at the Visual Studio auto-created TSQL code to create TSQL functions and try to create one using that code it also fails with the same message, so I know the TSQL code is correct (not missing a parameter, order, type, etc.).

It feels like something may be going on with the DB upgrade to 2012. I have tried compiling the assembly targeting .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 as well as targeting 2008 R2 database and 2012 database (so 4 combinations). The DB itself is using .NET 4.0 since it is in 2012 compatibility mode.

The database does have CLR enabled.

Any thoughts on how to get this working? Google has failed me so far.

**Edit**

The exact function signature (copied directly out of Visual Studio) is below (yes, a lot has been passed into this instead of having the CLR code query for data which, in our tests, has shown to have worse performance than passing everything in).

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlDouble udfGetCellValueCLR( 
        int MetricID, 
        string CSVDimensionList, 
        string AggregationSQLString, 
        string DateColumnForAverage,                         
        bool TimeFrameIsAVariance,
        bool TimeFrameIsAPlan,
        bool IsAnAverage,
        bool TimeFrameIsPercentOfTotal,
        bool AggregationAllowsPercentOfTotal,
        bool PlanAggregationAllowsPercentOfTotal,
        bool MetricIsAPercentage,
        int GoodDirection,
        int PlanMetricID,
        string PlanAggregationSQLString,                                                             
        int StartDateID, 
        int EndDateID,                                      
        bool NumeratorIsAPlan,
        bool NumeratorIsAnAverage,
        int NumeratorStartDateID,
        int NumeratorEndDateID,
        string NumeratorDateColumnForAverage,
        bool DenominatorIsAPlan,
        bool DenominatorIsAnAverage,
        int DenominatorStartDateID,
        int DenominatorEndDateID,
        string DenominatorDateColumnForAverage,                                   
        SqlString SpecialAggregation
    )
```

The TSQL CREATE FUNCTION statement is below (this is the one that errors).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [be].[udfGetCellValueCLR](
    @MetricID [int],
    @CSVDimensionList [nvarchar](4000),
    @AggregationSQLString [nvarchar](4000),
    @DateColumnForAverage [nvarchar](4000),
    @TimeFrameIsAVariance [bit],
    @TimeFrameIsAPlan [bit],
    @IsAnAverage [bit],
    @TimeFrameIsPercentOfTotal [bit],
    @AggregationAllowsPercentOfTotal [bit], 
    @PlanAggregationAllowsPercentOfTotal [bit], 
    @MetricIsAPercentage [bit], 
    @GoodDirection [int], 
    @PlanMetricID [int], 
    @PlanAggregationSQLString [nvarchar](4000), 
    @StartDateID [int], 
    @EndDateID [int], 
    @NumeratorIsAPlan [bit], 
    @NumeratorIsAnAverage [bit], 
    @NumeratorStartDateID [int], 
    @NumeratorEndDateID [int], 
    @NumeratorDateColumnForAverage [nvarchar](4000), 
    @DenominatorIsAPlan [bit], 
    @DenominatorIsAnAverage [bit], 
    @DenominatorStartDateID [int], 
    @DenominatorEndDateID [int], 
    @DenominatorDateColumnForAverage [nvarchar](4000), 
    @SpecialAggregation [nvarchar](4000)
)
RETURNS [float] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [EMMACustomCode].[UserDefinedFunctions].[udfGetCellValueCLR]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide the method signature and the exact `CREATE FUNCTION` statement that is getting the error.

Comment: method signature and `CREATE FUNCTION` code have been added

Comment: The signatures do at least appear to match. Have you tried loading the same Assembly on another instance and running this particular `CREATE FUNCTION` statement? You can even download a copy of SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB for a very light-weight install that is great for testing. I think we need to make certain that the code you are looking at in Visual Studio is what has been compiled into that Assembly. I do see that only one param is a `Sql*` type. I doubt that is the issue, but it is a difference. Ideally all params would be `SqlBoolean`, `SqlString`, `SqlInt32`, etc.

Comment: I created 2 brand new DBs on our 2012 DEV server (one in 2012 mode and 1 in 2008 mode) with nothing inside them. Loaded the assembly into it and in both cases, the `CREATE FUNCTION` failed with the same error. I have used iLSpy to open up the DLL (compiled from VS) and I see the code I expect to see in the DLL. I have been loading the DLL using HEX in TSQL - will try to use the file path loading option next.

Comment: I would expect the HEX to be fine. that is what I always use. But if the issue truly is the upgrade, that would be seen more clearly if you create a new instance (i.e. not an upgrade!). That is why I recommended LocalDB. It is a small download of a single `.msi` and a quick install (no services, etc).

Comment: Ill give that a shot. Our DEV and PROD instances are brand new 2012 servers, we just migrated our 2008 DB into the 2012 instance and set the compatibility mode to 2012. Can't hurt to try in a 2008 instance (we still have an old DEV server is 2008) as well as a new LocalDB in 2012.

Comment: is this happening on the new 2012 servers?

Comment: yes. both within the 2008 R2 to 2012 "upgraded" DB as well as a newly created 2012 DB on the 2012 instance and newly created 2008 DB created on the 2012 instance. Only step left to try is a 2008 instance (which I have access to...just need to set some stuff up on it first).

Comment: if you want to check the HEX vs the DLL, and the HEX version is already loaded, then just CREATE ASSEMBLY again but from the DLL and with a new name...it might error if they are identical..else you can check `sys.assembly_files` to compare their actual values.

Comment: So...it seems Visual Studio stopped updating the TSQL code to ALTER/CREATE an assembly using HEX - so I was using an old version of the DLL. When I loaded the DLL from a file instead of HEX, everything started working. Now to figure out how to get VS to generate the HEX for me again. Sorry to cause unnecessary work.

Comment: not a problem...where are you getting the hex from?...the _Create script or the publish script?..SSDT, by default, only updates when something changes, else it keeps as much as possible the same..

Comment: Well I now see the _Create script after checking the Create Script box in the Project Settings - but back in 2014 it was a different checkbox that didn't create the entire database, just the objects relying on CLR. Oh well, now that I know the issue I can get what I need from the _Create script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have used VS 2012, 2013, and now 2015 and don't recall that part changing. Either way, I will add an answer about checking the _Create script. I had a feeling you were not getting it from there.

Comment: @thomas Now that your issue is solved, you should consider answering your own question for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter list does not match, then there is in fact a difference between the Assembly (the one that has already been loaded into SQL Server) and the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

If you are using Visual Studio / SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to generate the Assembly and T-SQL wrapper objects, then you need to be aware that there are two types of SQL scripts that SSDT generates: Create scripts, and Publish / Deploy scripts.

**Create scripts** assume nothing about the current state of where they will be deployed. They will drop the Target Database if it already exists, then re-create the Database and load all of the objects (Assembly and T-SQL wrapper objects). The "{ProjectName}_Create.sql" script is not always generated. There is usually an option (check-box) on the "Project Settings" tab of "Project Properties" to enable the creation of this script. This script does not get deployed, it is just there for you to grab.

**Publish / Deploy scripts** are incremental deployments. These are created by SSDT by first examining the current state of the Target Database and only making the changes necessary to bring the Target up to the state of what is in the project (i.e. in the generated `.dacpac` file).

If you need to make sure that you have *everything* scripted that you have code for in your project, then make sure to have the "Create script (.sql file)" option enabled in "Project Properties" | "Project Settings", do a Build / Rebuild (no need to do a Publish), and then check the "Build output path" for the active configuration.

If you want just the changes, then you can use the "{ProjectName}.sql" script. However, you need to actually do a Publish (even to dev -- "Start without Debugging") in order to start the process that checks the current state of the Target DB. And even then, if there were no changes, the incremental Publish/Deploy script will not be created.

You don't need Visual Studio to generate the Publish script. You can do it via the command line using the [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx) utility (Action would be "Script").

Comment: Thanks. What I failed to do was Publish to get the Publish/Deploy script. I just did a build. That means I was referencing an old publish/deploy script and simply didn't look at the file creation timestamps. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Glad the info/questions were able to point you in the right direction :). And I just added some info to the end regarding generation of Publish scripts.